# Selecting the last record from a table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have three columns in a sql table which looks something like TYPE | REGISTRATION NR. | ID in a table called “cars”.
In the TYPE column is the vehicle model BMW, MERCEDES etc, in the REGISTRATION NR. is the registration number AB77TRR, UTYIE77 etc, and in the ID is, as the name suggest, the id 12, 13, 14 etc.
The problem is that in the ID column can be more than one id for the same model and registration like:

```
BMW AB77TRR 12  
BMW AB77TRR 13  
BMW AB77TRR 14
```

Most of the columns have only one id but there are some which have more id’s and I want to select only the last one registered and I cannot use LIMIT 1 or TOP 1.

If I run this select “select type, registration nr., id from cars where type in ( bmw, mercedes, audi, porsche)” it will show me all the records in the table ID and I want to show me only the last id.
For example if I run this select “select type, registration nr., id from cars where type in ( bmw, mercedes)” It will show me:

```
BMW      AB77TRR 12  
BMW      AB77TRR 13  
BMW      AB77TRR 14   
MERCEDES UTYIE77 11
```

And I want to look like:

```
BMW      AB77TRR 14 
MERCEDES UTYIE77 11
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Better to add unique index on type and registration no.

Comment: Add another MERCEDES to the sample data, with a different REGISTRATION NR, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should learn `SQL` basics from [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) by example, anyway this is a classic case of aggregate function MAX :

```
SELECT type, registration, MAX(id) FROM cars GROUP BY  type, registration
```

Comment: This would return every record from the sample data.

Comment: Poor sample data.

Comment: If these are the attributes in select clause then this solution is fine

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Bad sample data, or I just didn't read the question +1

Comment: I tried your variant before asking here but didn't worked, i figured now what was the problem, i had to use max also on type. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub-query to return each type's max id. JOIN with that result:

```
select c1.*
from carstable c1
join (select TYPE, max(id) as maxid
      from carstable 
      group by type) as c2
  on c1.TYPE = c2.TYPE and c1.id = c2.maxid
```

Comment: Why do you complicate it ?

Comment: @DanielE., the question isn't very clear. This is a great answer to the way I read the question.

Comment: I could'nt agreed more !

Comment: As per OP *The problem is that in the ID column can be more than one id for the same model and registration*, I guess you need group by model and registration no. not single attribute

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, I see what you mean, but I'll await adjusted sample data before I do any changes.